# PostgreSQL - Select Time Interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I have a DB as:

```
user  |  device  |  command  |  time
------+----------+-----------+------------
USER1 |   RT-001 | conf t    |  04-FEB-20 21:19:49
...
```

where `time` column is "*timestamp without time zone*" data type. I need to select data from the last 3 hours from now.
I use:

```
SELECT now() - INTERVAL '3 hours', user, device, command, time from mytable
```

but no sense. I also tried to tread `time` column as `text` but it also did not work:

```
SELECT user, device, command, time from mytable WHERE command_time LIKE '04-FEB-20%19:%'
```

I am not able to use % after 04-FEB-20 as this column is `time` data type.
So, how can I select last 3 hours of data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select user, device, command, time
from mytable mt
where mt.time >= (current_timestamp - interval '3 hours')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query could be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  user, 
  device, 
  command, 
  time 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE
  time BETWEEN (current_timestamp - interval '3 hours') AND current_timestamp;
```